# Проблемы с использованием java.util.UUID и Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-ee

Доброй ночи
Пытаюсь перевести приложение на использование UUID для id.

прописываю аннотации для id

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuidGen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuidGen", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="id")
private UUID id;
```

создаю таблицу в базе postgresql:

```sql
-- companies
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companies (
  id        UUID       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name      VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  email     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  website   VARCHAR(255) ,
  address   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created   TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  updated   TIMESTAMP
);
```

но при создании записи ловлю ошибку:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value
>   [ff80818159d26e3a0159d26fdaff0001] value by reflection : [class
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id] setter of
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value
>   [ff80818159d26e3a0159d26fdaff0001] value by reflection : [class
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id] setter of
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value
>   [ff80818159d26e3a0159d26fdaff0001] value by reflection : [class
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id] setter of
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id     ...
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value
>   [ff80818159d26e3a0159d26fdaff0001] value by reflection : [class
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id] setter of
>   net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.User.id
>
> ... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.UUID
>   field net.proselyte.crmsystem.model.BaseEntity.id to java.lang.String
>   ...

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Postgresql` есть встроенные функции для генерации значений первичных ключей с типом `UUID`. Они позволяют работать с первичным ключом по принципам, схожим с обычным числовым автоинкрементом. Сначала требуется включить расширение, позволяющее использовать функции генерации значений `UUID`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" schema pg_catalog;
```

Создавать первичный ключ таблицы следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companies (
  id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc(),
  ...
);
```

Кроме `uuid_generate_v1mc()` существуют и другие функции генерации различных типов `UUID`, смотрите документацию по расширению [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/uuid-ossp.html).

В `JPA`-сущности указываем так:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private UUID id;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно "uuid-ossp" schema pg_catalog и  DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc() не нашел информации.